# I can't manage to link a javascript to a button

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, javascript

I'm trying to create a extension with a lot of data processing involved but somehow I can't seem to link a basic button to do something. Also If you know any resources that will be helpful for me in the future I would be appreciated.

http://codepaste.net/vsimew

```
function helloworld() {
  alert("Hello World!");
}
```

This command is from popup.js I also have a background.js for listeners but I don't know how to use listeners.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

The reason that's not working is because inline Javascript is not permitted in extension pages.

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline `<script>` blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).
>
> The first restriction wipes out a huge class of cross-site scripting attacks by making it impossible for you to accidentally execute script provided by a malicious third-party. It does, however, require you to write your code with a clean separation between content and behavior (which you should of course do anyway, right?)

You can add an onclick handler using the `addEventListener` function; this section of the Chrome documentation provides an example on how to do that:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution